# Concurent access in hsqldb with JAVA Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, hsqldb

I write JAVA program by using multi thread, 
I have more than 5000 threads and each thread accesses the same table to insert or select data (Not to update).

I use HSQLDB (file mode) with Hibernate/Spring.

The reason that i use multi thread is to reduce execusion time, but table is access by One thread at the time.

I configure `hsqldb.tx=mvcc` for multi version control but any changes
Can some one know how to alow multiple thread to access the same table at the same time?

Comment: That's a ridiculous amount of threads you're using, and it definitely won't make anything faster, on the contrary. You should consider a real database too, I doubt HSQLDB can compare with products like MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: The problem is not the amount of thread, assume that my cpu have ability to run many thread at the time. The problem is that indeed the fact that i can run many thread for others operation, i can not do the same for database access. writting and reading transactions lock the data file.

Comment: Your CPU can run under 10 threads at the same time. 5000 threads is over 500 times the amount that can be run at the same time, so time is wasted a lot on just context switching between the threads. Very inefficient, you should read up on multithreading before attempting something like this.

Comment: @Kayaman - it won't be faster with MySQL etc. and HSQLDB compares very well with those databases

Comment: @fredt Yea, I hadn't looked up on HSQLDB's performance, so that might not be valid. But 5000 threads means that someone doesn't know how to multithread.... :)

Comment: @Kayaman - agreed on multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

Using more than one thread to SELECT from a table improves performance because the threads can access the same database table at the same time.

When multiple threads perform INSERT into a table, the INSERT statements must be executed one at a time by the database because there may be PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints that have to be checked in a queue to prevent inconsistencies in the database.

In any case, the computer is capable of running threads up the number of CPU cores at the same time. If you have more threads, they are queued by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I feel HSQLDB file mode,hsql mode and res mode do not support multithreading or multi user connection one at the same time. I am also detecting the required mode to perform the simultaneous tasks